# How to restore multiple default values on a Preference page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, preference

I am writing a plugin, which will do the job of restoring all default values of a Preference page in Eclipse. My idea is to get the Preference page, and then invoke: performDefaults() to reset all the values. However, I can't manage to get the Preference page of that plugin: I used the following code to get the IPreferenceNode, then I want to use method getPage() to return the corresponding Preference page of the plugin, but it returns null. It seems that IPreferenceNode doesn't store the associated Preference page. So How can I get the Preference page of a plugin? Or is there any other method to reset multiple values in a Preference page?

```
PreferenceManager prefmngr = PlatformUI.getWorkbench( ).getPreferenceManager();
List<IPreferenceNode> nodelist = pm.getElements(PreferenceManager.PRE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `performDefaults()` is not going to work as it expects to be run in an open preference dialog and calls user interface functions which will fail outside of an open dialog (it is also `protected` so you can't call it without reflection anyway).

Looking at a variety of preference pages there does not look to be any general way to reset a page's default.

Comment: About the protected method, I was going to use Reflection, if I can get the Preference page of the plugin :) And thanks to remind me that  even if I can manage to call the method, it won't work. I am thinking to get default scoped preferences of the plugin, and then try to use it to perform "restore default", what do u think? Is it feasible?

Comment: As I said the preference page will fail if it is not used as part of the preference dialog. `performDefaults` expects all the UI objects to have been created so it can set them to the default values. The preferences are not actually saved until `performOK` runs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my idea clearly. I agree with you that using the method : performDefaults() won't work. Now, I am thinking to get default scoped preferences related to the plugin, and then set the values back to Instance scoped preferences of the plugin, do you think it will be a feasible way to reset a page's defaults?

Comment: You may be able to do that, but you may need to run the plugin's preference initializer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advices, I will see where I can reach :)